# Jquery append after on click li doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Previously this was a `.hover` function and it worked just fine. Somehow after I changed it to onclick it doesn't work anymore.

What could be wrong? I tried changing little things here and there but it doesn't work either. I'm trying to append a button at the end of the `li` each time user clicks it, and assign a class "selected" to the `li`. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
$("ul#optionList li").on("click", function(){
  var test = $(this).attr('id');  //I still can get the ID

  $("ul#optionList li").removeClass('selected');  //  linesbelow don't work anymore
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='checkanswer2' id='"+test+"'>Check Answer</a>");
}, function(){
  $(this).children("a").remove();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='checkanswer2' id='"+test+"'>Check Answer</a>");
            }, function(){
            $(this).children("a").remove();
        });` ??

Comment: You can't pass two functions to .on() like you can to .hover().

Comment: Click is handled differently than hover - you can't just swap the keyword out.. Take a look at [the docs for jQuery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: when do you want to remove the anchor element? in the second click or when you click on another `li`

Comment: I want to remove the anchor element from other li, and append it into the second element that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should try it.

```
$("ul#optionList li").on("click", function(){
  var test= $(this).attr('id');  //I still can get the ID

  $("ul#optionList li").removeClass('selected');  //  linesbelow don't work anymore
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='checkanswer2' id='"+test+"'>Check Answer</a>");
  /*you can use it at the place of append
   $(this).after("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='checkanswer2' id='"+test+"'>Check Answer</a>");
  */
  $(this).children("a").remove();
});
```

please have a look on image for understanding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but not working as well. The append button doesn't show

Comment: please have a look on image, I have used same function it is working. May be you have missed something or I did not understanding your problem.

Comment: Hi , thank you very much. I used .after and it works fine. I'm wondering why we can't use append? I wanted it to be right beside the li and not underneath the li, and append does it just nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Since `.click()` does not take second handler and `.append()` does not take a callback function. I think you need to do:

```
$("ul#optionList li").on("click", function () {
    var test = $(this).attr('id'); //I still can get the ID

    $("ul#optionList li").removeClass('selected'); //  linesbelow don't work anymore
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='checkanswer2' id='" + test + "'>Check Answer</a>");
    $(this).children("a").remove();
});
```

Comment: The removing the class and adding the class works, but the append function doesn't seem to work. Is it I have to use some other function other than append?